# How can I reduce Chordal Action

Tags: chain, noise, vibration

I have an indoor, wheel on trainer - while indoors I notice the Chordal Action in the chain.

The Bike is a couple of years old now - I have replaced most consumable parts except, chainrings, bottom bracket and jockey wheels.

Shifting feels fine.

I do think my chain is pretty slack on the high gears - but only just about fits in the lowest.

Chain and cassette are fairly new, less than 500 miles.  Chain is lubricated with "Finish Line Ceramic Wax"

Would it help if I changed the jockey wheels ?

Comment: if this is a thing you only notice indoors, when there isn't air rushing past your face, i recommend listening to music or podcasts while you use the trainer

Comment: Take away the director's baton.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your chain is too long by a few links and/or an adjustment of your b screw could allow you to shorten the chain.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to larger chainrings and cogs. The old "standard" 53-39 rings and 12-something cassette were standard for a reason. The tightness of the chain doesn't really have anything to do with this problem.